# rtp multicast fails on win7 but success on Ubuntu, with live555 modifyied

Tags: rtsp, multicast, rtp, live555

I modified the live555 source code where sendto function locate.

I add a multicast after sendto function.

```
int bytesSent = sendto(socket, (char*)buffer, bufferSize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof dest); 
//zhouhua add below 
if(zhou_init == 0){ 
    zhou_init = 1; 
    memset(&mcast_addr,0,sizeof(mcast_addr)); 
    mcast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    mcast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.251"); 
    mcast_addr.sin_port = htons(5004); 
}
int k = sendto(socket, (char*)buffer, bufferSize,0,(struct sockaddr*)&mcast_addr, sizeof(mcast_addr)); 
printf("k = %d\n", k); 
//zhou end
```

It works when I play the rtsp stream. When I play a sdp file, it plays the  multicast video.

But, on win7, I can't get any response with vlc player.

While wireshark get the same multicast data on win7 and ubuntu.

Why it not work on win7 ?

Comment: just download it from http://live555.com/liveMedia/public/  and the key code is as below:

Comment: `code`int bytesSent = sendto(socket, (char*)buffer, bufferSize, 0,
               (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof dest);
//zhouhua add below
    if(zhou_init == 0){
        zhou_init = 1;
        memset(&mcast_addr,0,sizeof(mcast_addr));
        mcast_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        mcast_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.251");
        mcast_addr.sin_port = htons(5004);
       int k = sendto(socket, (char*)buffer, bufferSize,0,(struct sockaddr*)&mcast_addr, sizeof(mcast_addr));
       printf("k = %d\n", k);
//zhou end

`code`@zed

Comment: god... I dont know how to use this code format...

Comment: and now, I found vmware host can multicast with vmware host, but real host can't muliticast with wmware host.  and real to real can not ,either.

Comment: Add the code to the question, not a comment

Comment: @Zhou I copy the code you gave in comments in the post (adding a curly brace that seems missing. If I made mistake please fix it. Could you add the SDP file used to play the stream with VLC ?

Answer (score 0):

i'v found it .I should change the sdp file. the IP parameter should write int the end of the file.